# ElasticSearch terms aggregation on whole field

Tags: elasticsearch

This is mapping for my field:

```
{
  "product" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "product" : {
        "filters.brand" : {
          "full_name" : "filters.brand",
          "mapping" : {
            "brand" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fielddata" : true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get unique brands with doc count will following curl:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/product/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "aggs": {
        "domains": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "filters.brand",
                "missing": "N/A",
                "size": 10,
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

It is working ok except it is returning count by field tokens, not by whole field.

For example I have brand "Absolut Joy" and it returns result for them as separate tokens.

How to get aggregation for whole field?

ElasticSearch version: 5.3.1

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the mapping of `filters.brand`  as

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "brand": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And update the aggregation query to contain `"field": "filters.brand.keyword"`.

Use of `fielddata: true` for text is not advised. 
Refer: [Before-enabling-field-data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata)

For using same field for different purposes. Refer: [use-multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html)

Comment: It works. I thought that only solution is to use fielddata. Can you please point me to WIKI about aggregation when using keyword.... why is working with your example? Thank you very much

Comment: Refer this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html
And you can see the mapping for the same via `GET product/_mapping/field/filters.brand.keyword`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to change analyzer and search_analyzer.

```
"analyzer": "keyword",
"search_analyzer": "keyword"
```

Comment: Except if someone has better suggestion